# Converting String to Integer or object

Tags: java

I was wondering how I could convert user input using scanner to an integer that I have already declared. I have already created the object person1 and declared the variables firstName, lastName, age and gender in the 'Person' class. I know I should be using parse but I'm unsure how to implement it within my code.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Please input your details.");
        System.out.println("First Name:");
        person1.setFirstName(user_input.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Last Name:");
        person1.lastName = user_input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Age:");
        person1.age = user_input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Gender:");
        person1.gender = user_input.nextLine();
```

Lines 9 and 11 need modifying.

Comment: Don't want to count lines on your snippet code...

Comment: You can also use persont1.age=Integer.parseInt(user_input.nextLine());taking into consideration that at input your are entering only numeric values

Answer (score 0):

For the age, use :

```
person1.age = user_input.nextInt();
```